# how to create a table in hive using java?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive

I would like to create a table in hive using Java. Using the following way to do it:

```
public class HiveCreateTable {
    private static String driverName = "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // Register driver and create driver instance
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("haiiiiii");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:presto://192.168.1.119:8082/default", "hadoop", "password");
        con.setCatalog("hive");
        con.setSchema("log");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table access_log2  (cip string, csusername string, cscomputername string)");
        System.out.println("Table created.");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Query failed
>   (#20150731_101653_00008_hv68j): Unknown type for column 'cip'

Comment: Please add the error which you are encountering while run the above mentioned code.

Comment: getting this error.........
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20150731_101653_00008_hv68j): Unknown type for column 'eid'

Comment: Did you try using `cip String` instead of `cip string` ?

Comment: i tried using that too(cip string) but the same error encountered. I tried (eid int) i got the same error

Answer (score 2):

In the code above, you are using the Presto JDBC driver, not Hive. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but Presto supports the following data types, of which `String` is not one:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html